# Does a systemv message queue need to be closed

Tags: c, linux, message-queue, system-calls

I'm using a system v Message queue. The Queue is created and deleteted by an other process. So on this example I'm using the already created message queue:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
...
key = ftok(path,project);
msqid = msgget(key,0);
msgsnd(msqid,data,size,0);
//Must be the "handle" msgqid closed?
...
```

I can not find any information about closing the handle/identifier of the message queue. Does the message queue identifier has to be "closed"?

Comment: *Does the message queue identifier has to be "closed"?*  Before doing what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't.

SYSV message queues don't allocate specific resources (other than the queue itself and the messages posted in there) for clients that would need to be released. These resources are "global" to the system, not per process. `msgget` is just returning the key as a system global handle.

Destroying the message queue itself, however, should be done once it is no longer needed, as it occupies system resources. That is handled by "the other process", as you say, however.

Note that POSIX message queues (`mq_open, mq_close`) behave differently.

Comment: I don't think OP is asking about deletion of the queues. As they mentioned, creation and deletion is handled by another process. The question is about closing the handle in this process.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The deletion of the queue is done in the other process